# setting URL in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to install Adobe Creative Cloud SDK in my app. And according to their developer docs, they say, to set the sdk location in this way.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "${project.rootDir}/mvn-repo/release" //ADD THE CORRECT LOCATION OF THE CREATIVESDK LIBRARY FILES
    }
}
```

}

Now , the doubt is , right now the `SDK` in my system is located in ,

> D:\APPS\Futurister\FuTurister\app\creativesdk-repo

now, how do I add the correct location of creative sdk in gradle file?  Thanks,

Comment: Try like this: `repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
    }
}`

Comment: wait, whats bintray.com ?

Comment: ah, sr, it's an example. you could try: `maven {
        url "D:/APPS/Futurister/FuTurister/app/creativesdk-repo/release"
    }` that's the way to add repositories in local

Comment: if you use `$`, you need the function to get directory like: `maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/creativesdk-repo/release" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android Studio, to add repositories in local, you could set link manually by direct link:

```
maven { url "D:/APPS/Futurister/FuTurister/app/creativesdk-repo/release" }
```

or you could use `$` function to get directory, Ex:

```
maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/creativesdk-repo/release" }.
```